# About Adobe Gaming SDK?

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, adobe, cross-platform

I have no programming experience at all.  I've always wanting to know how to program games and have some fun with it.  I started with Corona SDK because I heard it was really simple (and it was very simple), but I decided against continuing in it (I had only programmed a character to jump until I realized --> ) because I realized that when I advance in it, I am going to end up having to pay for it.

In my search for a new cross-platform sdk to learn (since I don't have time, like most people, to learn and program 15 different apps in 15 different native languages), I found Moai SDK. I was turned away from Moai since its target audience are people with prior programming experience.

Later, I found Adobe Gaming SDK.  Although I doubt it is in any way as simple to pick up as Corona's Lua, if I figured if I have to learn something knew, I may as well learn something new that is as established as Adobe and their gaming SDK.

I have a few questions though...

1) What language does Adobe Gaming SDK use? (Pretty sure it is Action Script 3, but I do not know much about that either.)

2) Just how cross-platform is it? (Which devices?)

3) Where do I start!

4) Is it free?

`#`3 is the most important question for me since I don't have any programming experience, but I am willing to learn on my own. Honestly, I only want to learn how to program (2D) games; therefore, is there a source you can direct me to in order for me to learn from scratch and just gaming.

Any and all help is greatly appreciate!

P.S. If you have any other SDK or something that you think could suit me please help. Also, I am a cheap person, so i would prefer for resources to be free as well. **Also, please check back if you answered my question because I sometimes forget a question or will have a follow question since I am a major novice.**

## ***THANKS!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What language does Adobe Gaming SDK use? (Pretty sure it is Action
>   Script 3, but I do not know much about that either.)

Yeah, it's ActionScript3. You can also code in C/C++ using [CrossBridge](http://adobe-flash.github.io/crossbridge/).

> 2) Just how cross-platform is it? (Which devices?)

Using [Adobe Integrated Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_AIR) (AIR, for short), you can make your game available to several devices running iOS, Android and Windows, as long as they have the [minimum requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html) to run AIR.

Your game will also run on any browser with the Flash plugin, which includes Linux, Mac and Windows.

> 3) Where do I start!

There are plenty of materials about game development in Flash/Actionscript3, but I would recommend you to learn about a game engine first. It will make your life easier and will help you make a game faster (which will boost your motivation).

Two famous Flash game engines are [Flixel](http://flixel.org) and [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/). Start by checking these [GamedevTuts+](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/) guides: [how to learn Flixel](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn-flixel--gamedev-5843) and [how to learn Starling](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn-starling-framework--gamedev-10760) (there is an article about [how to learn Flash/AS3](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn/how-to-learn-flash-and-as3-for-game-development/) too).

> 4) Is it free?

Yes, all the tools you will need are free.

As a general advice, I would recommend you to take a look at [GamedevTuts+](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/). It has several resources about game development, from simple concepts to more advanced things. You will find articles for people with no programming experience at all. It's a great place to start as a novice game developer.

As a second advice, you could also use [Phaser](http://phaser.io) to create your games. It's an easy to learn HTML5 game engine, it doesn't require several tools to develop with (all you need is a code editor and a web server) and your game will run on any modern browser.

Comment: Thanks for this wealth of information! This is very much appreciated and exactly what I was inquiring.

Comment: You're welcome! I wish you all the luck on your journey!